# How to detect where SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON?

Tags: sql-server

I have a c++ application and run it on
SQL Server 2019

server1\db1 - it works fine
server1\db2 - it works strange

The app works different. I have detected in Profiler that db2 has

```
set implicit_transactions on
```

but the db1 has no this set.

I cannot find where this settings is: the app has no this statement.

Where it can be? may be implicitly?

Comment: are you setting "SET ANSI_DEFAULTS ON"  anywhere?

Comment: The "good " db I has sp_WhoIsActive (from A.Machanic) and I could run this proc earlier. But as I understand this setting shoudl be set for this session. The Profiler shows me that "set implicit_transactions on"  sends my app SQL:BatchStarting .   It is the reason  why the app works incorrectly.

Comment: No, I do not SET it . The  only difference is in db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the setting with:

```
select case when @@Options & 2 = 0 then 'Off' else 'On' end as Implicit_Transactions_State;
```

Ref: [`@@Options`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/options-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [user options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-options-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16#BeforeYouBegin).